# AMCharts - Data Points Not Visible in smaller resolutions

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

I have a problem where I don't get the data points when working on a smaller screen resolution of width 1680px.

[image]

When I reduce the browser width (Ctrl - -), I am able to see the data points.

[image]

Charts - AMCharts Line Series.Any help on this.

Comment: That's very weird. Can you post a codepen or fiddle that reproduces this?

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved.

I had given **minBulletDistance** in my code. Removing this populated the chart with all points.